# How to bind a port for outgoing requests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, port, adapter, firewall

I would like to bind a port for wanted the outgoing requests, so I could set rules to allow wanted outgoing traffic from this port and block all other ports for unwanted outgoing traffic.

By bind, I mean once set, any other request cannot take over that port.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47203137/12248597)

I found a similar question here. But it appears that the answer provides a way to use that port for outgoing request but cannot prevent other requests using that port for outgoing request.

Comment: Do you realize that a "request" sends data to a particular port on ANOTHER computer?  You can't block the other computer from doing something.  Nor can you block another program on your own computer from making any request it wants - if the OS allowed that, one program could break another.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am running another program in a sub process. I would like block all the outgoing traffic for that program and allow outgoing traffic from the main process. I am thinking to achieve this by using port binding.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work.  When the subprocess goes to make a request, it's going to choose a random port of its own.  It doesn't care one whit which port you are using.  You can't stop outgoing traffic.

Comment: @TimRoberts yup, I was thinking a way to bind the port somehow, so the other process couldn't use it. Sounds like it is impossible to bind the port

Comment: Right, because you don't know what port it's going to pick.  You might know the name of the destination port, but the source port number is chosen at random.

Comment: Which package are you using for making the request? With `socket`, that's possible to bind port for outgoing

Comment: @giladshefferI am using requests library. Could u elaborate or add the answer?

Comment: I think that's impossible using requests sadly

Comment: @giladsheffer could u elaborate the socket library solution? I can change library for sure