# Specifying an outgoing port with Python requests (revisited)

Tags: python, python-requests

I have found the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202790/python-requests-how-to-specify-port-for-outgoing-traffic) to this quite helpful, however an error is encountered whenever there are two http requests sent in rapid succession:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.140', port=8082): Max retries exceeded with url: /dev2/presence/notpresent (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xb5dbff30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 98] Address already in use'))
```

Sometimes I can recover via sleeping and retrying, but often it just keeps repeating.

It appears that the resource has not been released in time for the next request.  Is there a way I can force a reset somehow to avoid this problem?

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Comment: My app has to be sending messages from a specific port.

Comment: I find that very, very hard to believe, especially for an HTTP server.  I'd be more likely to believe that you have misunderstood the requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but if you disagree with the premise of the original question, or the proposed solution, then I would suggest you express your opinion on the original post linked above.  I am not confused about my requirements.   Here, I'm trying to understand the underlying reason for why the originally-given solution fails in certain cases.